# The domain name specified for the docker container started by cloud-run has not taken effect

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run

As the title says, I've been stuck here for two days now, and I haven't been able to map my custom domain name to the docker-run container.

https://hello-world.rxliuli.com/ => https://hello-world-nzgzxtw2lq-uc.a.run.app/

[image]
[image]
[image]

Test results at mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx
[image]
All other dns pointing to github.io are in effect
[image]
The rxliuli.com domain is verified on Google Console
[image]

I don't know what happened, please let me know if you need additional information

Comment: If the Cloud Run custom domain mapping is not working after an hour, you made a mistake. Double-check that you are creating resource records at the authoritative name servers for the domain. Delete the domain mapping and the resource records that you created and start over. Use Internet tools such as MxToolbox to verify that the required resource records are public with the correct values. https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx

Comment: mxtoolbox tells me that dns records cannot be found, I added a screenshot, but all other dns pointing to github.io are normal, I'm not sure what happened

Comment: I just deleted and re-added the new dns (gcloud and cloudflare), I will wait for a day. . .

Comment: The DNS configuration is working now. However, your endpoint is sending multiple 302 redirects. It appears that you are checking if the client is using HTTPS and then redirecting if not. Your service's code needs to correctly detect the client protocol (HTTP or HTTPS). Look at the HTTP header **X-Forwarded-Proto**. Create a new question as that is a different topic. Tip: Your backend code only needs to support HTTP. The Cloud Run frontend (GFE) proxies HTTPS -> HTTP for your service. Open a command prompt and run this command to see the 302s: **curl -I -L https://hello-world.rxliuli.com/**

Comment: In the end, I solved this problem by turning off the proxy function of cloudflare. Although I am not very sure what happened, this problem may occur with the two-layer https proxy.

Answer (score 1):

The domain propagation time for Cloud Run (fully managed) is typically 24 hours. Although the SSL certificate can be obtained within 15 minutes, the entire procedure can take up to 24 hours.

If the domain is still not working after 24 hours, it means that something went wrong during the configuration phase or a step was overlooked. Here is the documentation for [Mapping Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains).

Putting and removing records could be the primary solution, as John mentioned.

I'd suggest giving it some time between attempts.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the 24 hour propagation time? I am not disagreeing with you, I am looking for something to add to my answers on Cloud Run. In the three years plus a hundred plus deployments, I have not seen the time take more than 15 minutes and usually less time. However, once someone makes a DNS resource record mistake the DNS negative response caching kicks in which can delay resolution for a much longer period of time. The key is to configure the DNS server correctly the first time.

Comment: You are correctly mentioning that it usually takes 15 minutes or less, but in some cases it could take up to 24 hours.
Now, according the Google documentation: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#limitations, there is a point that mentions that:
Provisioning the SSL certificate usually takes about 15 minutes but can take up to 24 hours (2nd point).

Comment: Thank you, Jose.

Comment: I updated some information about the problem